# Is there a way to predict that a customer will churn in next 30 days

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

I have trained a classifier that classify customers as churn or not churn and data contains transaction amount, last transaction date and demographics. Also the definition for churn is that there is no transaction initiated by customer for 12 months. The classifier works well, Now coming to Question: 
I want to see will a customer churn in next 30 days or not. As per my understanding a ML classifier just puts the cases in respective classes.

please share any recommendation as we can classify in future or not